# Add other field to String in IF-Statement

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query with an IF-Statement. If one field is empty, it should output a String with the value from another field.

```
SELECT  IF(field1  IS NULL or field1    = '', 'Field is empty but field 2 says field2', field1   )AS field1 FROM...
```

When I enter the query like above it will only output the string

> Field is empty but field 2 says field2

The output should be

> Field is empty but field 2 says 5 *(5 is the value of the field)*

I also tried putting the field to into quotes, but that throws out a mysql-error.

I think maybe the way with the quotes is right, but I'm missing a string connector or something like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use `CASE`.  `IF()` is MySQL-specific.  `CASE` is standard and available in most databases.  But the answer to your question is `CONCAT()` or `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL OR field1  = ''
             THEN CONCAT('Field is empty but field 2 says ', field2)
             ELSE field1
        END) AS field1
FROM ... ;
```

I like to write such formats using `REPLACE()` as well:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL OR field1  = ''
             THEN REPLACE('Field is empty but field 2 says {0}', '{0}', field2)
             ELSE field1
        END) AS field1
FROM ... ;
```

This makes it easier to see what the final string will look like.

Comment: I chose the Replace method. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not smart enough to know how to dynamically inject a variable value into the string. It just outputs the literal value you specified. You will need to concatenate it:

```
SELECT  IF(field1  IS NULL or field1    = '', CONCAT('Field is empty but field 2 says ', field2), field1   )AS field1 FROM
```